# MBox Viewer for large files

Tags: windows, gratis, email, gmail

I retrieved a backup of my email account with [Google takeout](https://www.google.com/settings/takeout). The back up a Gmail account is a `.mbox`. As a result, I'm looking for a program that would:

- be able to view a large .mbox, i.e. larger than 10 GB and ideally larger than 50 GB (since my Gmail account is around 50 GB). [Windows MBox Viewer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mbox-viewer/) didn't work for me even with a 1.4 GB .mbox file, which seemed to be too large for it.

and if possible:

- work on Windows 7, but other Windows or Linux is OK too
- free
- doesn't need to configure a POP account beforehand (I think [Mozilla Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/thunderbird/) requires it but I'm not sure about that one)

Comment: Have you tried Nodemailer app? https://nodemailer.com/app/

Comment: @BarathVutukuri thanks I haven't tried it yet but it looks quite useful!

Answer (score 1):

You could try loading the MBOX file into an IMAP server that uses MBOX for back-end storage.  I believe Dovecot does this.  Then you could browse the mailbox with an IMAP client.

Comment: Could you give details (the main steps) about this process, for example for Windows?

Comment: Moreover, the MBOX file can be viewed by most text editors, such as Microsoft Word, Open Office Writer, and Notepad. The MBOX file stores email messages in a text file.

Comment: Sure it's text, but it's one long text file including all the mails and various escape sequences to delineate them.  It's fine if you just want to find the odd message, but it's no use for random access, or multi-result searching etc

Answer (score 0):

How about converting your big single file to a series of linked web pages with indexes and such?  Then you can view in a browser, etc.

If that will work for you, check out `mhonarc` - https://www.mhonarc.org/MHonArc/doc/mhonarc.html