# mbox viewer on OS X

Tags: osx, email

I am looking for a mbox viewer on OS X. It should

- run natively on OS X 10.9
- be able to view and search large mbox files (>10000 messages) efficiently
- display and preserve all information present in the mbox file.

It would also be nice if it could let GPGTools decrypt encrypted messages.

Any suggestions? (It doesn't have to be free.)

Comment: It's still early, but you might try [Mailpile](http://mailpile.is). Last time I tried it I could import an mbox file and search it.

Comment: @GregHewgill Mailpile has an appealing design, but so far Thunderbird does the job for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/thunderbird/) with the [ImportExportTools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/) extension:

- Free, open source, Windows/LinuxMac
- ImportExportTools can import mbox files

[image]

[image]

From a review:

> ImportExportTools worked flawlessly, importing my 350 Eudora v7.1
>   mailboxes (with 117k emails) into Thunderbird 3.0 on a Windows 7
>   machine.

(FYI: [MBox Viewer for large files on Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2102/903))

Comment: Very nice add-on. Perfectly suited for my needs. Decryption of PGP protected messages is possible as well.

Comment: @ben Good to know about the decryption of PGP protected messages, I hadn't tried that.